# A simpler way to create a dictionary with counts from a 43 million row text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset, analysis

Context:  I have a file with ~44 million rows.  Each is an individual with US address, so there's  a "ZIP Code" field.  File is txt, pipe-delimited.

Due to size, I cannot (at least on my machine) use Pandas to analyze. So a basic question I have is:  How many records (rows) are there for each distinct ZIP code?  I took the following steps, but I wonder if there's a faster, more Pythonic way to do this (seems like there is, I just don't know).

Step 1:  Create a set for ZIP values from file:

```
output = set()

with open(filename) as f:
  for line in f:
    output.add(line.split('|')[8]  # 9th item in the split string is "ZIP" value

zip_list = list(output)  # List is length of 45,292
```

Step 2: Created a "0" list, same length as first list:

```
zero_zip = [0]*len(zip_list)
```

Step 3: Created a dictionary (with all zeroes) from those two lists:

```
zip_dict = dict(zip(zip_list, zero_zip))
```

Step 4: Lastly I ran through the file again, this time updating the dict I just created:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    next(f)  # skip first line, which contains headers
    for line in f:
        zip_dict[line.split('|')[8]] +=1
```

I got the end result but wondering if there's a simpler way.  Thanks all.

Comment: I always think that when the datasize is large enough, you should look into a database solution, it makes for memory efficient retrievals

Comment: Agree, though this time it was a quick 'sanity check' on the output file (*.txt) coming from the DB team, so a 'one off' type of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the `zip_dict` can be replaced with a `defaultdict`. If you can run through every line in the file, you don't need to do it twice, you can just keep a running count.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split('|')
        d[parts[8]] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm not very familiar with collections module yet, though I did watch a video talk by the creator of "collections". I'll explore those.  And yes, it's 9th item, index 8.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple using the built-in Counter class.

```
from collections import Counter

with open(filename) as f:
    c = Counter(line.split('|')[8] for line in f)
print(c)
```